# Not Retrieving All Entries in Channel

Tags: channel-entries, structure

I have a page that is supposed to return all of the entries for a channel, but it only retrieves the first. The channel is "annual-2014".  The channel is assigned "publications/index" in Structure.  The URL is

```
humbleisdfoundation.org/publications/annual-2014

======== publications/index ========

{if "{segment_2}" == ""}

    <h3>Publications</h3>

    <ul>

    {exp:channel:categories category_group="2" style="linear"}

        <li><a href="{category_url_title}">{category_name}</a></li> 

    {/exp:channel:categories}

</ul>

{if:else}

{embed="publications/content" channelName="{segment_2}"}

{/if}

==== publications/content ======

    {exp:channel:entries channel="{embed:channelName}" orderby="date" sort="asc"}

    {absolute_results} <=== Always returns 1 even though there is more than one entry

    ...

    {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the dynamic="off" parameter to your channel:entries tag

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="{embed:channelName}" dynamic="off" orderby="date" sort="asc"}
```